# What is a good (free) VM solution for windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualbox, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

The obvious candidates are Virtualbox and Virtual PC.

But I have not been paying attention to VM's the last year, have I missed a good alternative?

Comment: What lacking for you from the VM stuff built into Win 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VMWare player is also free to use, and can create virtual machines as well.

Comment: Wow, I did not even realize VMWare Player could create VM's now.  Kinda makes Workstation 7 a hard sell, eh?

Comment: Yes, I tried it out when I had audio issues with VBox, and it works slick. Every bit as easy as VBox.

Comment: Just note, VMWare player is licensed for non-commercial use only.

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with VirtualBox? That's still the best free one I've ever used.

Comment: I've had audio problems with VBox running an XP guest.

Answer (score 2):

I agree. I find VirtualBox has the best feature set of any of the VM solutions out there and its free.

I have yet to see another VM app support the seamless mode feature of VirtualBox which IMO is the one of the coolest VM features out there.

Comment: Do you mean the only *free* VM solution that supports seamless mode? Both Parallels and VMWare support this (but are not free). Also, Parallels, at least, does a better job of it than VirtualBox.

Comment: VMWare Player is free and does support seamless mode.

Comment: @DCookie: Doesn't seamless mode require installing VMware Tools? And doesn't installing VMware Tools require something other than VMware Player?

Comment: This link: http://www.vmware.com/support/player30/doc/releasenotes_player3.html seems to indicate that it does have this feature. I'm pretty sure that VMWare asked me if I wanted Tools installed when I built the VM XP guest.

Comment: That said, the reviews I've seen comparing the two seem to favor VBox. I just can't make it work with the audio on my W7 host.

Comment: virtualbox has its own tool set which comes with vbox  but yes you do need to install the tools in the guest OS in order to activate fullscreen and seamless modes you may need it for the sound drivers as well but im not 100% sure on that im currently running vbox in windows 7 and have no problems with sounds but cant remember if i had sound before installing the tools i want to say it didnt but im not 100% sure

Comment: Actually, both VMWare and Parallels support a seamless mode but VirtualBox doesn't. That is, VirtualBox technically does, but it does not hide the taskbar which will happily float on the screen over or under the host OS' taskbar or just above the Dock on Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

I install custom laptops for our users, many who need access to dual OS'. Since we started using a minimum of 4GB on laptops I've recommended virtualbox whether the host is windows or linux, the guest OS always being the opposite.

I use this myself, and all users I've set this up for have been very happy with the results, which are much better than dual-booting, although with lower performance, which is very seldom necessary anyways.